# CONSULTA MYSQL multittabla y con 2 SUM

Tags: mysql

necesito ayuda si alguien puede asistirme, tengo una consulta multitabla, que esta funcionando y trae datos de varias tablas, y los lista, que es la siguiente.

```
SELECT usuarios.id, 
    usuarios.nombre, 
    usuarios.apellido, 
    estado.descripcion AS estado, 
    deposito.descripcion AS deposito, 
    grupos.descripcion AS grupo, 
    contacto.telefono, 
    contacto.telefonoAlt,
    DATE_FORMAT(usuarios.fechaIngreso, '%d-%m-%y') AS fechaIngreso, 
    DATE_FORMAT(contacto.desde, '%H:%I') AS desde, 
    DATE_FORMAT(contacto.hasta, '%H:%i') AS hasta, 
    queBuscan.descripcion as categoria, 
    queBuscanSub.descripcion as subcategoria, 
    usuarios.email

FROM usuarios  
LEFT JOIN estado  ON usuarios.idEstado = estado.idEstado
LEFT JOIN deposito  ON  usuarios.idDepo = deposito.idDepo
LEFT JOIN grupos  ON usuarios.idGrupo = grupos.idGrupo
LEFT JOIN contacto ON usuarios.id = contacto.id
LEFT JOIN queBuscan ON contacto.idQueBuscan = queBuscan.id
LEFT JOIN queBuscanSub ON contacto.queBuscanSubId = queBuscanSub.id

WHERE  usuarios.userTipeId = 2;
```

El problema me surgió al querer integrar a esta consulta un campo mas que es el de SALDO
que se obtiene de 2 tablas distintas, ya que una es de depósitos y otra de reintegros.
Ya tengo una consulta que me esta funcionando, pero para un cliente en especifico. La consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(monto),0) FROM depositos  WHERE id = $id ) - (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(monto),0) FROM reintegros  WHERE id = $id ) AS resultado
```

Como podría integrar ambas consultas? Desde ya Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIONADO

```
SELECT usuarios.id, usuarios.nombre, usuarios.apellido, estado.descripcion as estado, 
            deposito.descripcion as deposito, grupos.descripcion as grupo, contacto.telefono, contacto.telefonoAlt,
            DATE_FORMAT(usuarios.fechaIngreso, '%d-%m-%y') as fechaIngreso, DATE_FORMAT(contacto.desde, '%H:%I') as desde, DATE_FORMAT(contacto.hasta, '%H:%i') as hasta, 
            queBuscan.descripcion as categoria, queBuscanSub.descripcion as subcategoria, usuarios.email, (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(monto),0) FROM depositos  WHERE id = usuarios.id ) 
            -(SELECT IFNULL(SUM(monto),0) FROM reintegros  WHERE id = usuarios.id ) AS resultado
            from usuarios  
            LEFT JOIN estado  on usuarios.idEstado = estado.idEstado
            LEFT JOIN deposito  on  usuarios.idDepo = deposito.idDepo
            LEFT JOIN grupos  on usuarios.idGrupo = grupos.idGrupo
            LEFT JOIN contacto on usuarios.id = contacto.id
            LEFT JOIN queBuscan on contacto.idQueBuscan = queBuscan.id
            LEFT JOIN queBuscanSub on contacto.queBuscanSubId = queBuscanSub.id
            WHERE  usuarios.userTipeId = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Es muy dificil dar una respuesta si no compartes la estructura de tus tablas. Te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Asumo que un usuario puede tener varios depositos y reintegros. Por lo tanto tu consulta devolvera para cada usuario todos sus depósitos y el saldo actual (total depósitos - total reintegros), o sea que por cada usuario verás varias veces el saldo total actual.

Me llama la atención que en las tablas depositos y reintegros la columna "id" sea el id del usuario, un nombre mas apropiado hubiera sido usuario_id.

Creo que esta query tendrá mejor rendimiento que la tuya (ya que tu calculas el saldo total para cada fila), pero conociendo el model de datos seguramente se pueda elaborar una query mejor.

Habría que evaluar si no conviene vincular con el usuario en cada una de las subqueries (td y tr) y restringir solo los usuarios tipo 2 (como en la query) para no calcular el saldo de todos los usuarios (ya que la query solo muestra información de las usuarios tipo 2).

```
SELECT usuarios.id, 
    usuarios.nombre, 
    usuarios.apellido, 
    estado.descripcion AS estado, 
    deposito.descripcion AS deposito, 
    grupos.descripcion AS grupo, 
    contacto.telefono, 
    contacto.telefonoAlt,
    DATE_FORMAT(usuarios.fechaIngreso, '%d-%m-%y') AS fechaIngreso, 
    DATE_FORMAT(contacto.desde, '%H:%I') AS desde, 
    DATE_FORMAT(contacto.hasta, '%H:%i') AS hasta, 
    queBuscan.descripcion as categoria, 
    queBuscanSub.descripcion as subcategoria, 
    usuarios.email,
    IFNULL(td.total, 0) - IFNULL(tr.total, 0) AS saldo

FROM usuarios  
LEFT JOIN estado  ON usuarios.idEstado = estado.idEstado
LEFT JOIN deposito  ON  usuarios.idDepo = deposito.idDepo
LEFT JOIN grupos  ON usuarios.idGrupo = grupos.idGrupo
LEFT JOIN contacto ON usuarios.id = contacto.id
LEFT JOIN queBuscan ON contacto.idQueBuscan = queBuscan.id
LEFT JOIN queBuscanSub ON contacto.queBuscanSubId = queBuscanSub.id

LEFT JOIN (SELECT id AS usuario_id, SUM(monto) AS total 
           FROM depositos 
           GROUP BY id) AS td ON td.usuario_id = usuarios.id

LEFT JOIN (SELECT id AS usuario_id, SUM(monto) AS total 
           FROM reintegros 
           GROUP BY id) AS tr ON tr.usuario_id = usuarios.id

WHERE  usuarios.userTipeId = 2;
```